# Could the imperius curse wake up someone dosed with the draught of living death?

Tags: harry-potter, unforgivable-curse

**Considering that the imperius curse can be fought only through sheer willpower**, and considering sleep, even a magically induced sleep, is a state of high vulnerability, could the imperius curse be used to wake someone from their slumber **if only for
as long as they are under the influence of the curse?**

More generally speaking this raises the issue of potion and spell interaction, and how much, with a few exceptions, potions seem to be underestimated in the series as a means of direct action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would posit that you could cast it on someone under the effects of the Draught of living death, depending on how you interpret imperius works which I take it as you control the body via the mind by making overpowering suggestions to the person you are controlling. This means that whilst under the effects of The draught, imperius would not work as the brain of the other person would be unable to wake their own body and thus unable to control it.

Comment: Indeed.Well, wiggenweld potion it is then... thanks for your answer!